# How to fetch users by company or school information

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

How do I search for FB users who worked in a certain company (e.g. Microsoft)

How do I search for FB users who studied in a certain school (e.g. Standford University)

What query should I use to fetch the above information?

Comment: What have you tried, and what specifically are you having trouble doing? Have you checked the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Work and education history require specific [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) in order to get them for a specific users. Facebook wouldn't give it to you any other way, it's private information.

Generally you can only search by name in the Graph API, not by properties.